# Error happening in safe_iterator.h when I compile my code

Tags: c++

Alright, guys. I know I already posted this code (which I've now fixed from how it was before), but there still seems to be something going on and I don't want to edit my previous post to include another question (since that's against the rules).

When I compile code below, I get an error message from deep within a library

```
safe_iterator.h: **error: no match for 'operator<' in '(+ __lhs)->__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence>::base [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >, _Sequence = __gnu_debug_def::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >]() < (+ __rhs)->__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence>::base [with _Iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >, _Sequence = __gnu_debug_def::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >]()'**
```

Any ideas? Please don't be too harsh on me. I'm a bit of a n00b. :)

```
// Returns the mode (most common element) of an integer array
int mode(int* arrPtr, int size) { 
    assert (size > 0);
    std::map<int,int> M; 
    for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) 
        M[arrPtr[k]]++;
    std::pair<int,int> maxpair(M.begin()->first, M.begin()->second);
    for (std::map<int,int>::iterator it = M.begin() + 1; it < M.end(); ++it) 
        if (it->second > maxpair.second) maxpair = *it;
    return (maxpair.first);
}
```

Comment: Ah! I believe it's a problem with your for loop on the iterator. You don't say it<M.end(), you say it!=M.end(). So I think it's complaining about the iterator M.end() not having a less than operator defined.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators do not implement `operator<`

You should use `it != end`, beware of `size` being zero!